# How to reuse code in Oracle Script?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a script where I am creating some test data. At the beginning of the script I create some tables where I have to insert the data. Before creating them I check that they do not exist.

```
declare
 tableExists number;
begin

SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO tableExists
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name = 'MY_TEST_TABLE';

if tableExists>0 then
    execute immediate 'drop  table MY_TEST_TABLE';
end if;

SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO tableExists
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name = 'MY_TEST_TABLE2';

if tableExists>0 then
execute immediate 'drop table MY_TEST_TABLE2';
end if;

--Here I create both tables: MY_TEST_TABLE and MY_TEST_TABLE2
```

My question is:
Is there a way to avoid repeating the code for checking if the table exists? Is there a way that I could call that code as a method passing the table name as parameter?

I believe I could create/declare a function and then use that. But that kind of function is not temporal. I know this is not like C or C++. But I was wondering if there was a way I could have a sort of "private method" for this script to test the existence of my tables and that way I wouldn't have to repeat the code, but the method wouldn't remain after my script was finished.

What is the correct way, if there is any, to achieve what I want?

Comment: Rather than dropping and re-creating everytime, create once (or when table structure changes), truncate and reload data. or that is not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always nest blocks in PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
  <<define your other local variables>>

  PROCEDURE drop_if_exists( p_table_name IN VARCHAR2 )
  AS
    l_num_tables pls_integer;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO l_num_tables
      FROM user_tables
     WHERE table_name = p_table_name;

    IF( l_num_tables = 1 )
    THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || p_table_name;
    END IF;
  END drop_if_exists;
BEGIN
  drop_if_exists( 'MY_TEST_TABLE' );
  drop_if_exists( 'MY_TEST_TABLE' );

  <<more code here>>
END;
```

Comment: I had to change the where clause to: WHERE table_name = UPPER(p_table_name); Because sometimes they could send the table name in lower case and in the user_tables the table names seem to be saved in Upper Case

Answer (score 1):

you could put your table into a temporary table or a table of varchar2.
ex:

Instantiation :

```
create global temporary table gpt_name(table_name varchar2(64)) on commit preserve rows;
insert into gpt_name values('MY_TEST_TABLE');
insert into gpt_name values('MY_TEST_TABLE2');
```

..

code:

```
declare
 tableExists number;
begin
for line in (select * from gpt_name )
loop

SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO tableExists
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name =line.table_name;

if tableExists>0 then
    execute immediate 'drop  table  '||line.table_name;
end if;
end loop;
end;
```